# ¿Como buscar un objeto por una llave (ej id) dentro de un array multidimensional?

Tags: javascript, recursión

Estoy usando una función recursiva la cual consiste en buscar un `array` por su llave `id`, cuando la consiga corta la repetición de la misma y devuelve el `array`. Es la única manera que se me ha ocurrido para buscar el `array` que es lo que necesito. Si hay otra manera, bienvenida sea, pero no conseguí nada y es lo que se me ocurrió.

El problema que tengo es que me retorna **undefined**.

```js
let partes = [
  {
    "id": 317,
    "nombre": "Estación de Corte",
    "padre": 0,
    "conteo": 2,
    "partes": [
      {
        "id": 320,
        "nombre": "Ventosas",
        "padre": 317,
        "conteo": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Estación de Formación",
    "padre": 0,
    "conteo": 2,
    "partes": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "nombre": "Placas",
        "padre": 1,
        "conteo": 1,
        "partes": [
          {
            "id": 305,
            "nombre": "Superior ",
            "padre": 8,
            "conteo": 2
          },
          {
            "id": 306,
            "nombre": "Inferior",
            "padre": 8,
            "conteo": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "nombre": "Estación de Calentamiento",
    "padre": 0,
    "conteo": 1,
    "partes": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "nombre": "Placas",
        "padre": 4,
        "conteo": 1,
        "partes": [
          {
            "id": 9,
            "nombre": "Placa Superior de Calentamiento",
            "padre": 7,
            "conteo": 1
          },
          {
            "id": 10,
            "nombre": "Placa Inferior de Calentamiento",
            "padre": 7,
            "conteo": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 341,
    "nombre": "Sistema de Descarte",
    "padre": 0,
    "conteo": 2,
    "partes": [
      {
        "id": 342,
        "nombre": "Dedos de Retension",
        "padre": 341,
        "conteo": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 334,
    "nombre": "Sistema de Refrigeracion",
    "padre": 0,
    "conteo": 2,
    "partes": [
      {
        "id": 336,
        "nombre": "Evaporador",
        "padre": 334,
        "conteo": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 335,
        "nombre": "Compresor",
        "padre": 334,
        "conteo": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 338,
        "nombre": "Condensadora",
        "padre": 334,
        "conteo": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 337,
        "nombre": "Partes Electricas",
        "padre": 334,
        "conteo": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 339,
    "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
    "padre": 0,
    "conteo": 10,
    "partes": [
      {
        "id": 340,
        "nombre": "Camaras",
        "padre": 339,
        "conteo": 10
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 309,
    "nombre": "Estación de Sellado",
    "padre": 0,
    "conteo": 2,
    "partes": [
      {
        "id": 310,
        "nombre": "Placas",
        "padre": 309,
        "conteo": 5,
        "partes": [
          {
            "id": 311,
            "nombre": "Inferior",
            "padre": 310,
            "conteo": 5
          },
          {
            "id": 312,
            "nombre": "Superior",
            "padre": 310,
            "conteo": 5
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 315,
        "nombre": "Leva",
        "padre": 309,
        "conteo": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 314,
        "nombre": "Muelles",
        "padre": 309,
        "conteo": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 313,
        "nombre": "Esparragos",
        "padre": 309,
        "conteo": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 316,
        "nombre": "Resortes",
        "padre": 309,
        "conteo": 1
      }
    ]
  }
];

function obtener_array(array, id) {
  for (n in array) {
    if(id === array[n].id){
    return array[n];
     break;
    }
    if (array[n].partes) {
      obtener_array(array[n].partes, id);
    }
  }
}

let graphic_array = (obtener_array(partes, 310));
console.log(graphic_array);
let graphic_datos = graphic_array.partes;
console.log(graphic_datos);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te está devolviendo un error debido a que tu función está devolviendo `undefined` y, por lo tanto, no puede obtener un atributo (el array `partes`) de algo que no existe.

Te recomiendo que realices un control (un if) para controlar que si `graphic_array` tiene contenido, lo muestre por pantalla y, si no, que no muestre nada. También que si `graphic_array` contiene el array `partes` lo muestre y, si no, no muestre nada.

Como estás usando una función recursiva, **tienes que obtener también el objeto que te devuelve la función**.

Posteriormente, si el objeto tiene datos, que lo devuelva.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```js
let partes = [
  {
    "id": 317,
    "nombre": "Estación de Corte",
    "padre": 0,
    "conteo": 2,
    "partes": [
      {
        "id": 320,
        "nombre": "Ventosas",
        "padre": 317,
        "conteo": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Estación de Formación",
    "padre": 0,
    "conteo": 2,
    "partes": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "nombre": "Placas",
        "padre": 1,
        "conteo": 1,
        "partes": [
          {
            "id": 305,
            "nombre": "Superior ",
            "padre": 8,
            "conteo": 2
          },
          {
            "id": 306,
            "nombre": "Inferior",
            "padre": 8,
            "conteo": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "nombre": "Estación de Calentamiento",
    "padre": 0,
    "conteo": 1,
    "partes": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "nombre": "Placas",
        "padre": 4,
        "conteo": 1,
        "partes": [
          {
            "id": 9,
            "nombre": "Placa Superior de Calentamiento",
            "padre": 7,
            "conteo": 1
          },
          {
            "id": 10,
            "nombre": "Placa Inferior de Calentamiento",
            "padre": 7,
            "conteo": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 341,
    "nombre": "Sistema de Descarte",
    "padre": 0,
    "conteo": 2,
    "partes": [
      {
        "id": 342,
        "nombre": "Dedos de Retension",
        "padre": 341,
        "conteo": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 334,
    "nombre": "Sistema de Refrigeracion",
    "padre": 0,
    "conteo": 2,
    "partes": [
      {
        "id": 336,
        "nombre": "Evaporador",
        "padre": 334,
        "conteo": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 335,
        "nombre": "Compresor",
        "padre": 334,
        "conteo": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 338,
        "nombre": "Condensadora",
        "padre": 334,
        "conteo": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 337,
        "nombre": "Partes Electricas",
        "padre": 334,
        "conteo": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 339,
    "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
    "padre": 0,
    "conteo": 10,
    "partes": [
      {
        "id": 340,
        "nombre": "Camaras",
        "padre": 339,
        "conteo": 10
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 309,
    "nombre": "Estación de Sellado",
    "padre": 0,
    "conteo": 2,
    "partes": [
      {
        "id": 310,
        "nombre": "Placas",
        "padre": 309,
        "conteo": 5,
        "partes": [
          {
            "id": 311,
            "nombre": "Inferior",
            "padre": 310,
            "conteo": 5
          },
          {
            "id": 312,
            "nombre": "Superior",
            "padre": 310,
            "conteo": 5
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 315,
        "nombre": "Leva",
        "padre": 309,
        "conteo": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 314,
        "nombre": "Muelles",
        "padre": 309,
        "conteo": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 313,
        "nombre": "Esparragos",
        "padre": 309,
        "conteo": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 316,
        "nombre": "Resortes",
        "padre": 309,
        "conteo": 1
      }
    ]
  }
];

function obtener_array(array, id) {
  var objeto = {};
  
  for (n in array) {
    if(id === array[n].id){ 
      return array[n];
      break;
    }else if (array[n].partes) {
       objeto = obtener_array(array[n].partes, id);
    }
  }
  
  if(objeto){
     return objeto;
  }
}

let graphic_array = obtener_array(partes, 310);
if(graphic_array.id){
  console.log(graphic_array);
}else{
  console.log("El id no se encuentra en el array de objetos.");
}


if(graphic_array.partes){
  let graphic_datos = graphic_array.partes;
  console.log(graphic_datos);
}
```

Comment: La cuestión es que ese **id** si se encuentra en el array multidimensional. Puedes verlo en **Estación de Sellado** el primer item es **Placas** el id es **310**, el cual fue el que coloque en el ejemplo.

Comment: @PabloContreras Vale, perdona, entonces la duda es... ¿el id que quieres buscar es en partes o quieres que busque cualquier id, tanto dentro como fuera del array partes?

Comment: Tranquilo, que ubique la llave **id** sea igual al que se envía por parámetro y devuelva el objeto partes que contiene.
Si notas en mi ejemplo, puedes editar y probar, el **for** localiza el array pero no devuelve el valor del mismo.

Comment: @PabloContreras Mi duda es si tiene que buscar entre los id que hay en el array partes o entre los id que hay fuera de ese array. O entre todos los id.

Comment: si, tiene que buscar entre todos los id que hay entre todos los **array** de todas las dimensiones.

Comment: @PabloContreras He editado la respuesta añadiendo la recursividad (que antes no había aplicado). Creo que esto es lo que buscas.

Comment: Gracias hermano :D